# Asp.net video management

Tags: asp.net

How can i find **duration of an uploaded video**,****convert it to flv format**** and then **create a thumbnail from the video** in an asp.net web application?

I've tried using ffmpeg.exe, but is it suitable for a heavy traffic site?If so please suggest a suitable method to tackle the issues due to heavy traffic....

I need the simillar functionality seen in youtube.

Any one please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ffmpeg for our CMS which handles numerous uploads a day. What I do is pass if off to an asynchronous page, queuing up requests which it then works through.

Don't quote me on this, but I *think* YouTube has used ffmpeg in the earlier days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.If you can explain how you used the asynchronous page and the queuing up the requests, it will be more helpful to me.

Comment: Try reading this article. Has good info and a few examples of async pages in asp.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Comment: Hi  Bigfellahull,
           Can you suggest a method to access the errors, if any happened during the execution of the ffmpeg.exe through command prompt, in my C#.net code.

Answer (score 0):

For free that's your best option so far I know. If a paid service it's an option you may consider these 2 services

- encoding.com
- heywatch.com